# pywinauto - .children() under CS data grid is giving me win32_controls.EditWrapper - Edit - not rows and columns

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have a custom CS datagrid with some thousands of records, they are also editable at the sametime if I double click I can enter some data as well if it's drop-down I can choose a value. So in the code I'm writing something like below fetching me only class types as below. So my requirement is to traverse through columns and rows to get data as well to edit the data by clicking on specific cells:

```
win32_controls.EditWrapper - '', Edit
win32_controls.ComboBoxWrapper - '', ComboBox
win32_controls.EditWrapper - '', Edit
```

Below is the piece of code I'm writing

```
table = app.top_window().window(title_re='Exchange Rate Options.*')
t1 = table.child_window(class_name='CSCtrlGrille')
t2 = t1.children()
```

i have same table with multiple records, but the problem is im unable to perform click operation on the records below scroll bar. so how scroll down and click on desired record?

below is the inspect tool shows the properties list as,

[image]

Grid information from Inspect.exe, what is VirtualizedItemPattern meaning? Let me know if furhter info required.

[image]

added below Row1 Inspect.exe info,

[image]

also adding subtree (hidden) info of Row1 and i see diff which is highlighted in red box

[image]

Comment: Did you try to change `Application()` to `Application(backend="uia")`? If the result is similar, is it possible to take a look at some sample application with similar grid? I could not find any kind of this grid in the Internet.

Comment: i could able to get data when i use uia, thanks for the answer. however i have another challenge. let me edit question

Comment: Can you provide `Inspect.exe` screenshot for the grid? Not the whole window. Is VirtualizedItemPattern available for it?

Comment: added grid info from Inspect.exe in above question. plz let me know if you require further info

Comment: Well, this is another case, no VirtualizedItemPattern available is a good luck so far. I need `Inspect.exe` info about one particular row by selecting from tree (ideally invisible one) with expanded subtree of cells.

Comment: added Row1 and subRow info in above

Comment: added hidden row details in above, i see a difference of property 'IsOffScreen=true' compared to others rows.

Comment: Well, it's not that easy. Is it possible to prepare sample application with such grid to download and debug?

Comment: not really sure, this is a vendor app. do you think any other ways works?

Comment: I thought it's possible to prepare some demo app (without private info). Or we can schedule Skype call this weekend.

Comment: thanks, will reach out